# How to use a different baseUrl for one particular call?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

In my app I make Axios calls to my API whose `baseUrl` is defined in an `.env` file. But, In one isolated call I need to query a different API. Can `BaseUrl` be overridden on a call basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes.

`baseURL` will only be prepended to `url` if `url` is not absolute.

Lets say you have defined a `baseurl` as `https://google.com`.

Then calling a relative url like `axios.get('/user?ID=12345')` will call `baseurl+url` like this: `https://google.com/user?ID=12345`.

But calling an absolute url like `axios.get('https://facebook.com/user?ID=12345')` will only call `url` like this: `https://facebook.com/user?ID=12345`, even if you have `baseurl` defined.